# Make gvim 7.2 background black

Tags: vim, vi

I am sick and tired of the white background when I edit C/C++ etc. I want the black backround. That is what I currently have in my .vimrc file in regard to coloring. Please help me change it:

```
if !has('gui_running')
    set t_Co=8 t_md=

highlight NORMAL  ctermbg=black ctermfg=white
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
:help colorscheme
```

For example:

```
:colorscheme torte
```

Or, [find a color scheme you like at vim.org](https://vim8.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=dark&script_type=color+scheme&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search).

Comment: Also, look into the Color Sampler Pack in the vim script catalog.  My personal favorite is vividchalk.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Colors are controlled with the `:highlight` command  [Vim documentation: syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3ahighlight) , which allows you to specify colors for gvim (`guifg` and `guibg`) differently from colors for terminal vim (`ctermfg` and `ctermbg`).

All you have to do is make sure that the colors you assign to `guifg` and `guibg` are the same as you assign to `ctermfg` and `ctermbg`. Here's a script that might get you going: [Xterm256 color names for console Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Xterm256_color_names_for_console_Vim)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your colorscheme, the following command might work (it does depend on the colorscheme).

```
:set background=dark
```